# MySql - How do i set a new value when it matches a criteria?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ID, Division, EffectiveDate, PM, Status, Name, Address, ProjectType
FROM intranet.t_bidinfo
WHERE Division = 'TI'
AND EffectiveDate >= curdate()
AND Status = 1
ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC
;
```

I need to change the return value of `Status` to 'Active' instead of 1 in my sql statement, how would i go about doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case statement:

```
SELECT ID, Division, EffectiveDate, PM, case Status when 1 then 'Active' end as Status, Name, Address, ProjectType
FROM intranet.t_bidinfo
WHERE Division = 'TI'
AND EffectiveDate >= curdate()
AND Status = 1
ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC
;
```

Comment: this works but presents a new issue, the column header now has a new name `case Status when 1 then 'Active' end`